# How to share Database connection pool between shiny apps under ShinyProxy

Tags: r, database, connection, pool, shinyproxy

In my practice, many shiny apps needs to access Postgresql DB which installed on host.
I use pool package to get connection pool of Postgresql, and set it to global variable shared for other apps.
But every new user trigger app, it would get new connection of Postgresql.
I'm afraid Postgresql would crash down when too much concurrent users use shiny apps.
Is any solution for this secenario?

pool package introduction as bellowing url.
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `pool` only works in its own process. If each app is served by its own process, then ... each app needs its own instance of `pool`. Database connections (whether from `pool` or direct) cannot be shared between processes. As long as one process can serve multiple users within the same app, though, `pool` will work between users (assuming they are all sharing the same credentials, usually controlled via env-vars or similar).

Comment: thanks to @r2evans. So under ShinyProxy infrastructure, is there any other solution for sharing Database Connection pool between diferrent shiny apps?

Comment: You might consider `pqbouncer`, described briefly in https://scalegrid.io/blog/postgresql-connection-pooling-part-1-pros-and-cons/. Since shinyproxy is java, perhaps there's a driver or an analog in java for the "connection pool" concept. Good luck!

Comment: thanks to @r2evans. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've install pgbouncer, and it solved the problem. Thanks a  lot!